# How do function descriptors work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, python-3.x, descriptor

I was reading [a presentation](http://www.aleax.it/Python/nylug05_om.pdf) on Pythons' Object model when, in one slide (number `9`), the author asserts that Pythons' functions are descriptors. The example he presents to illustrate is similar to this one I wrote:

```
def mul(x, y):
    return x * y

mul2 = mul.__get__(2)
mul2(3) # 6
```

Now, I understand that the point is made, since the function defines a `__get__` it is a descriptor as I described in the description section of the Python documentation.

What I don't understand is how exactly the call results in the output provided.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's Python doing what it does in order to support dynamically adding functions to classes.

When `__get__` is invoked on a function object (usually done via dot access `.` on an instance of a class) Python will transform the function to a *method* and *implicitly* pass the instance (usually recognized as `self`) as the first argument.

In your case, you *explicitly* call `__get__` and *explicitly* pass the 'instance' `2` which is bound as the first argument of the function `x`, here `2` is considered the "instance" `self`:

```
>>> mul2
<bound method mul of 2>
```

This results in a method bound on the instance 2, with one expected argument that yields the multiplication: calling it returns `2` (the bound argument assigned to `x`) multiplied with anything else you supply as the argument `y`.

Normally, `function()` invokes it's `__call__` with the appropriate arguments provided:

```
mul.__call__(2, 3)  # 6
```

---

As a plus, a Python implementation of `__get__` for functions is provided in the [Descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) document of the Python Docs.

Here you can see the transformation, with the usage of [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType), that takes place when `__get__` is invoked :

```
class Function(object):
    . . .
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        return types.MethodType(self, obj, objtype)
```

And the source code for the intrigued visitor is located in `Objects/funcobject.c`.

As you can see if this descriptor did not exist you'd have to automatically wrap functions in `types.MethodType` any time you'd want to dynamically add a function to class which is an unnecessary hassle.